What are the key differences in the demographics and support base of DNSAP in Austria compared to Germany before Anschluss?
During the interwar years, the DNSAP in Czechoslovakia comprised a more varied group of members compared to their German counterparts. This was due to the party's nationalistic stance in Czechoslovakia, which was divided along ethnic lines and promoted the unification of Sudetenland. Similar to the Austrian version of the party, I am interested in understanding the distinctions between the Austrian and German parties and how their supporters were dispersed across the country. It would be helpful to have a visual representation, such as a map, included in the response. Thank you.

Sutherland? Not Sudetenland?

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)  The question would also be stronger if it includes links to terms that are not part of common English discussion (e.g. DNSAP, the Austrian version of the party)

Try to get a hold of "Statistik der Nationalratswahlen des Jahres 1920. 2. Zergliederte Darstellung", in Beiträge zur Statistik der Republik Österreich, vol. 11, 1921. Google does not seem to have a scan of this volume. References in the literature suggest that these election statistics are broken down to the district level, which would allow you to prepare your own map. Statistics for the 1927 election, published as "Die Nationalratswahlen vom 24. April 1927" in a special issue of Statistische Nachrichten (1927), seem likewise hard to track down. I have not been able to find a scan.

Volume 10 of Beiträge zur Statistik der Republik Österreich suggests that the DNSAP was an insignificant party (< 1%) in the 1920 election, but contains this interesting tidbit: "Die stärksten Männerüberschüsse weisen die Nationalsozialisten und vor allem die Kommunisten auf ...", i.e. national socialists and especially communists were significantly more popular with male voters than female voters.

The entry for the Austrian national election of Nov. 17, 1923 in the German Wikipedia does not mention the national socialists at all. It is my understanding that it was not uncommon in elections for a small party to join forces with a larger party rather than field its own independent slate of candidates; maybe that happened in this case? Strangely, the Wikipedia article dates the 1923 election to Oct. 21 in the summary at the top, while the historical source it used for the election statistics clearly states Nov. 17.
